# How to give to the creator of a node the option to hide the name of the author?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I need to provide a way for hiding the name of the user who created a node, if the creator of a node wants to do so. In such cases, it should show *Anonymous* as the author of the node.

Any suggestions about how to implement this?

Comment: look at following setting in node form,
http://screencast.com/t/MsI2dX2Gy

Comment: @makbuk as you said "Just showing anonymous user as author." then look at my comment above

Comment: Can you update your use case and full story behind this question in this post? To me, there are too many unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things in [the original version of this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/209278/1) that really need review ...

> Content may add only authorized users on my site.

In Drupal you cannot have content that adds users, so I'm going to assume it's rather the opposite you're looking for, ie: "*Content may **only be added by** authorized users on my site*".

> I need to implement the functionality (option) of hiding a user name (author of сontent) if user wishes it.

Unless you have special customizations in place in your site, Drupal allows for ***multiple (authorized) users*** to author (change) content. So your "***if user wish it***" is a not clear enough: maybe you mean "the original author" (who first created the node), or maybe you mean "the user who last edited (changed) the content". For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to assume "the original author".

> That is, to make him/her "the anonymous author of" сontent.

If you agree with my above assumptions, here is a blueprint of how you could implement this:

1. Add a custom field to your content type, which is a boolean (true/false, yes/no, 0/1, whatever fits) that can be used when creating a node to have the original node author indicate if author should be shown (yes) or marked as "anonymous" (no).
2. Use the [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to ensure that the "Authored by" value always remains the "original node author" (who created the node). This basically ensures that attempts to change the node author (similar to what is suggested in [codenext](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/52479/codenext)'s answer) will be rejected. Only using [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) should be sufficient to implement this (rather basic) validation. But if needed (to further enhance these validations), add the [Rules Forms Support](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) module.
3. Use a preprocess function in your theme (similar to what is suggested in [Zuzuesque](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/32083/zuzuesque)'s answer) to actually display the node author as requested by ... the original node author.

Note that if the original node author ever want to change his/her mind, that's still possible with this approach: just change the value of the custom field value as desired (after doing so, the logic in step 3. will ensure it's processed accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is provided by Default in Drupal,

> [image]

If I write my name: it will show:

```
Submitted by codenext on Wed, 07/20/2016 - 11:14
```

If I leave blank: it will shown:

```
Submitted by Anonymous (not verified) on Wed, 07/20/2016 - 11:14
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I tried this module, unfortunately, if you activate the option Author By, users can select the name of any registered user (it is not suitable) or leave it blank for display Anonim. In my case, I need only the ability to hide name if the user wants it.

Comment: But if you are looking for this, It is by default in Drupal. If you create any content, there is a option of `leave block for Anonymous`, which has to be handled by that author. Are you looking something else?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, this option is not active for Authorizing users (it is available to the administrator), it can be enabled by using the module of which you wrote earlier Override Node Options, but in this case, it does not look good on the entry form. In my case it is better to use for this custom field as described in this decision. Thanks again for your help and attention.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a single 'best way' to do this. An easy way would be to add a boolean field to your content type and call it something like 'post anonymously' or 'hide my username'.

Then it depends where you want to show the information. If you are using the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) this is particular easy:

1. Add the field for user name and hide it from display.
2. Add the boolean field.
3. Under the no result behavior of the boolean field (check the option to count 0 as an empty field) and output your username + any optional text like authored by.
4. Rewrite the boolean field and add your text for anonymous authors.

**If you are not using Views** you will want to use a proprocess function to manipulate the part of the page you display the author name on - e.g.: if you want to change how the author is shown on the node itself use [`template_preprocess_node(&$variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x):

```
YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if($node->type == 'your_node_type') {
    //change text if author wants to stay anonymous (else keep original)
    if ($node->field_your_bool_fieldname[0]['value'] == 1) {
      $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by anonymous on !datetime', array('!datetime' => $variables['date']));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think, this feature is available by default in drupal.

Comment: You will need the Views module (if you want to output your node using views), but I included how to change the display of the username if you only want to use core drupal, e.g. the default node pages.

Comment: Please can you look at my answer's image. The drupal by default provide, What user name you wan to add or you wan to leave it blank so anonymous will appear. Please let me know if I did not understood. Thanks

Comment: In your approach the user can select ANY user in the system as author - but that's not what makbuk wants if you read his comments. Anonymous (not verified) doesn't look too pretty either.